# Does the browser send its own certificate to the Web server during https communication?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am completely new to the concepts of SSL/https.

My question is, does the browser send its own certificate to the web server during https communication? If yes then where on the client’s computer the certificate is stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A  browser can send a certificate if the server requests it and it has one. Where those client certs are stored depends on the browser and operating system.

Comment: But if the server does not ask for the certificate how does the server encrypt the information that needs to be sent to the client? And how does the client decry-pt that information?

Comment: @surajnaik Encryption and decryption is done using session key, not a certificate. And session key is exchanged using key exchange algorithm backed by server's certificate for security. You really should read an article or a book about SSL - all those topics are covered by many of them.

Comment: @surajnaik: this is usually referred to as "client-certificate authentication" or "SSL/TLS mutual authentication". (This is used for client authentication.)